# Tkinter Photo Image Issues

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run sample code and I am running into a problem where sublime says "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\atave\Dropbox\Python\tkinter Python Tutorial\Labels\prac.png". Can anyone tell me why? I have already set up sublime as an exception in the firewall, does it have to do with the location of the image?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# create the root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Label Widget Image')

# display an image label
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\atave\\Dropbox\\Python\\tkinter Python Tutorial\\Labels\\prac.png")
image_label = ttk.Label(
    root,
    image=photo,
    padding=5
)
image_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It may be because the image is not a PNG image actually, or the version of the tkinter does not support PNG image.

Comment: Note that PNG is supported in `tk` version 8.6+.

Comment: Is the file actually a png file, or did you take some other file such as .gif and rename it to png?

Answer (score -1):

the `tk.PhotoImage` doesn't work that well with `.png` files. I would suggest conversion to `.bmp` file or using PIL(Pillow) module- `tk.PhotoImage(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\atave\\Dropbox\\Python\\tkinter Python Tutorial\\Labels\\prac.png")`

The `ImageTk` in `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` is imported from PIL(`from PIL import ImageTk`)

Comment: `tk.PhotoImage()` does not support the result from `PIL.Image.open(...)`.  Need to use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()` instead.

Comment: It should be something like `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="...")`.

Comment: modern versions of tkinter handle png without a problem.